# Put me before new

Tags: riddle, word

> *Put me before new
>
>   I make it too new!
>
>   My root is burning wood.
>
>   I identify!
>
>   Every company needs me, that's why.
>
>   Mark me, but how?
>
>   I am one!
>
>   Now, what am I?
>
>   Worry not—I will help you;
>
>   I am a word
>
>   that defines all of me.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's

> BRAND.

Details:

Put me before new
I make it too new!

> BRAND NEW

My root is burning wood.

> A brand is a torch, a burning piece of wood. I think this is the original meaning from which (most of?) the others derive.

I identify!
Every company needs me, that's why.

> A brand is a corporate identity.

Mark me, but how?
I am one!

> I think this is a reference to branding of livestock, in which their owner's *brand*, a distinctive mark, is burned onto the animals. (Derived from the "burning wood" meaning. Led to the "corporate identity" meaning.) *OP adds*: You use a brand to mark things, but you can't really brand a brand. In the second line, `one` implies that a brand itself is a mark.

Now, what am I?
Worry not—I will help you;
I am a word
that defines all of me.

> I think the rest of the poem is just stating the puzzle and doesn't
>  contain other specific clues.

Comment: Great! Just the kind of answer I was looking for.

Comment: You didn't upvote the puzzle, I think. Why? Was it too "weak"?

Comment: I don't upvote most puzzles; maybe a few percent of all puzzles posted.

Answer (score 4):

> Brand?

Explanation:

Put me before new
I make it too new!

> BRAND new

My root is burning wood.
I identify!

> You can BRAND wood with marks

Every company needs me, that's why.

> A BRAND is how you recognise a company.

Mark me, but how?
I am one!

> Not sure on this one.

Now, what am I?
Worry not—I will help you;
I am a word
that defines all of me.

> Or these.

Edit: @Gareth got there before me.

Comment: I've edited the puzzle to make better sense.

Comment: And you missed a line in between.

Comment: For lines 6 and 7: you use a brand to mark things, but you can't really brand a brand.

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine eh?